# React with Cypress problem when using jQuery

Tags: jquery, reactjs, cypress

I run the following test in Cypress.

```
it('click button', () => {
    cy.visit('localhost:3000');
    let $li = Cypress.$('.myClass');
    cy.wrap($li)
        .click({force:true})
})
```

and receive the following error message:

[image: Error message]

> CypressError: Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: '.myClass', but never found it.

My React code looks like:

```
<Button className='myClass'>myButton</Button>
```

Can you please let me know where the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
it('click button', () => {
    cy.visit('localhost:3000');

    cy.get('.myClass')
        .click({force:true})
})
```

Probably react didn't rendered your element yet. Cypress commands like `get` mentioned above handle this problem for you.